# Is it possible to automatically check a polynomial to determine whether it has integer coefficients?

Tags: polynomials, coefficients

Given a polynomial f, I want to determine whether f has integer coefficients.  More specifically, define

```
M[f_]:=MonomialList[f].
```

Is it possible to determine whether the coefficient of `M[f][[k]]` is an integer for k between 1 and `Length[M[f]]`?

Comment: Take a look at [CoefficientList](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientList.html) and [IntegerQ](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerQ.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in function IntegerQ[a] which returns true if a is an integer:

```
f[x_] := 1/2 + 2 x + 3/4 x^2
IntegerQ[#] & /@ CoefficientList[f[x], x]

{False, True, False}
```

Either you can use the pure function constructs above with the #, & and @ which basically feeds into the IntegerQ function, each coefficient from the monomials of f or just do it sequentially as

```
   myCoef = CoefficientList[f[x], x]
   IntegerQ[myCoef[[1]]]


Out[8]= {1/2, 2, 3/4}

Out[9]= False
```

Comment: `IntegerQ/@ CoefficientList[f[x], x]` is ok.

Comment: Thanks for that!